# JPEG picture's pixels aren't exactly 0 or 255

Tags: python, image-processing, jpeg, image-compression

I have added a threshold to an image using cv2 library

```
image = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\***\\***\\Workspace\\Payment Advice 3 page - 3.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imwrite("C:\\Users\\***\\***\\Workspace\\Payment Advice 3 page - 3 - thresh.jpg", thresh)
```

and then I exported pixel values to CSV file

[image]

as per their documentation

> Here, the matter is straight-forward. For every pixel, the same
> threshold value is applied. If the pixel value is smaller than the
> threshold, it is set to 0, otherwise it is set to a maximum value. The
> function cv.threshold is used to apply the thresholding. The first
> argument is the source image, which should be a grayscale image. The
> second argument is the threshold value which is used to classify the
> pixel values. The third argument is the maximum value which is
> assigned to pixel values exceeding the threshold.

the color values should be the minimum value or maximum value defined in the code block (as per my understanding)

but in exported csv file there are some values between the maximum and minimum value,

is this normal behavior or did I miss anything?

(I'm a beginner in image processing)

Comment: did you know that JPEG is **lossy** compression? [tour], [ask], [mre]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for the direction, I have changed the image format to .png